# I want make html option checked with condition from mysql data

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, if-statement, foreach

so how to make condition in echo php, i have code
the scanario is, data will edit and ind option will output value checked at same in database

```
<select required="" class="form-control select2_category" name="dokter">
   <option>Pilih Dokter....</option>
     <?php foreach ($dokter as $r) {
        echo "<option value='$r->dokter_name'>$r->dokter_name</option>";
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please add your php code with the query and show what you have tried

Comment: On what basis you want to check selected options means on what condition it should be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it

```
<select required="" class="form-control select2_category" name="dokter">
   <option>Pilih Dokter....</option>
     <?php foreach ($dokter as $r) {

        $selected = '';
        if($r->dokter_name == 'data that comming from table' )
          $selected = 'selected';
        else
          $selected = '';

        echo "<option $selected value='$r->dokter_name'>$r->dokter_name</option>";
       }
    ?>
```